# jQuery.find() a form into an element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, find

dynamically i generate a formular into a defined div-container and i would like grab the send-action for sending with ajax.

The generate HTML:

```html
<div class="mhuntform">
<form action="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST">
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>A text</p>
<div id="form" style="padding: 5px 0px;">
<p>
<label for="email" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px;">E-Mail</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail" style="width: 60%;">
</p>
<p>
<button name="mhskl_send" id="mhskl_send">Anmelden</button>
</p>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

The Formular is defined by the admin into the wordpress-page. In Javascript (jQuery) i know only the classname of the div-container (here .mhuntform). So in Javascript i try to catch the event:

```js
// mhuntskl.options.container = '.mhuntform'
$(mhuntskl.options.container).find('form').submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var email = $(mhuntskl.options.container).find('input[type="email"]').val();
    var res = $.ajax(mhuntskl.options.ajaxurl,{async:false,data:{action:'subscribe',email:email},dataType:'json',type:'POST'}).responseText;
    res = $.parseJSON(res);
    if (res.success) {
        $(mhuntskl.options.container).hide();
    }
    return false;
}
```

But unfortunately the submit-event will not catch and if i prints the containter with find into the console `console.log($(mhuntskl.options.container).find('form'))` it will received an empty object only.

What i make wrong here?

Comment: Is this returning 1 - *console.log($(mhuntskl.options.container).length)*

Comment: The key question here is **when** are you running your Javascript?

Comment: @Adrian i use it into `$(document).ready(function(){});` statement.

Comment: @Krasimir `console.log($(mhuntskl.options.container).length);` is 1 and `console.log($(mhuntskl.options.container).find('form').length);` is 0

Answer (score 0):

If *console.log($(mhuntskl.options.container).length);* is 1 and *console.log($(mhuntskl.options.container).find('form').length);* is 0 then there is only one possible reason. Your form is still not inside the *.mhuntform* div when you execute the code. Is that form generated by another javascript. If not, then is the js code wrapped in *$(document).ready*.